# Can a common mode choke be used at the output of an SMPS?

Tags: common-mode-choke

If there is CM EMI on DC power supply lines, can a CM choke be used at the output of SMPS supply? Im asking because all CM examples I saw are for AC power lines.

Comment: It certainly can be used on an output like that. Make sure that it is used with output capacitors to ground though because, on its own it is only 50% of a solution.

Comment: Thank you you could write this as an answer, do you mind if I open a more specific question about that? About Smps caps and using ferrite core at particular EMI freq

Comment: I’ll wait in case anyone else contributes because I’m unable to make a proper detailed answer at the moment.

Comment: I see; my other question here anyway: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/411067/what-value-and-type-of-capacitors-must-be-used-after-cm-chokes-for-a-known-emi-f Im sure will not get much attetion as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can a CM choke be used at the output of SMPS supply?

Common mode chokes (in conjunction with the appropriate filter capacitors to ground) can certainly be used on the output of a SMPS: -

[image]

Picture taken from [Maxim Tutorial 716](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/app-notes/index.mvp/id/716) - see section entitled "Common-Mode Noise". Although not always needed (if one rail of the output is grounded), for low output noise applications they tend to be used along with a regular LC filter.